# React useffect infinite render or stale state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting some posts from the server and every time i delete or add a post, i need to refresh the page for it to showcase the changes. This can be solved by adding posts in the dependency array but then an infinite render occurs.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getUsersData = async () => {
      const results = await getUsers();
      setUsers(results.data);
      console.log(results.data);
    };

    const getPostData = async () => {
      const results = await getPosts();
      console.log(results.data);
      setPosts(
        results.data.sort((p1, p2) => {
          return new Date(p2.created_at) - new Date(p1.created_at);
        })
      );
    };

    getUsersData();
    getPostData();
  }, [posts]);
```

---

```
{post.user_id === user.result.user_id && (
              <DeleteIcon
                color="secondary"
                onClick={() =>
                  handleDelete(post.post_id, { user_id: user.result.user_id })
                }
              />
            )}
```

__

```
export const deletePost = async (postId, userId) => {
  await axios.delete(`${URL}/posts/${postId}`, { data: userId });
};
```

Comment: define your `getUserData()` and `getPostData()` outside the `useEffect` hook. then you can have a `useEffect` with and empy dependency array that calls those functions and from your `deletePost` function you can call `getPostData()` aswell

Comment: @coglialoro thank you, this worked well. Managed to use the same logic and make it work for the post as well :)

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getPostData = async () => {
      ...
      setPosts(
        ...
      );
    };
    getPostData();
}, [posts]);
```

Oops !
The issue is here, you are setting your post each time you... are setting your posts !
Maybe you should use setpost somewhere else in your code ? :)

If you want to update your posts, you should do it in another useeffect, with whatever dependencies you need to know you need to update your poste. Or do a timed refresh, also in a use effect. You can then call setpost, without having access to post. You don't need post as dependency to update it, on the contrary, that's what's causing a loop here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add `posts` as a dependency to your `useEffect` ince you are using that effect to call `setPosts`. This will cause an infinite rerender loop.

Your issue is one of the reasons why many fetch libraries for react have been created in the last few years, like `react-query`, or `RTK query`, because what you want to do, is to update your queried data, in response to a mutation on the  same data-set on server *( mutations: POST, DELETE, PATCH, PUT )*. These libraries let you specify what query data to revalidate once you perform a mutation, in your case, you would tell your *getPosts* *query* to be reexecuted and revalidated in cache everytime you perform an `addPost` or `deletePost` mutation.

If you want to implement manually both optimistic update and cache revalidation, you need to add some more code, you will have basically these code blocks:

```js
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])


const getUsersData = async () => {
    const results = await getUsers();
    setUsers(results.data);
    console.log(results.data);
 };

const getPostsData = async () => {
    const results = await getPosts();
    console.log(results.data);
    setPosts(results.data.sort((p1, p2) => {
          return new Date(p2.created_at) - new Date(p1.created_at);
        })
      );
    };

const handleDelete = async (postId, userId) => {
    await deletePost(postId, userId) // DELETE Call
    const idx = posts.findIndex(p => p.id === postId )
    setPosts(posts => [...posts.slice(0, idx),...posts.slice(idx+1, posts.length)] // Optimistic update of UI
    getPosts()  // Revalidate posts after the delete operation
}

const handleAddPost = async (post, userId) => {
    await addPost(post, userId) // POST Call
    setPosts(posts => [post,...posts] // Optimistic update of UI
    getPosts()  // Revalidate posts after the POST operation
}

// Retrieve data on the first component mount

useEffect(() => {
    getUsersData();
    getPostData();
  }, []);
```